# Is it a good idea to check if user has already registered an iCloud email and alert if they have?

Tags: user-behavior, feedback, validation

I think checking coincidences between an user email with another email but with the *@icloud.com* extension would be a great feature to add on a registration process.

This would be a great way to try not to have more than 1 registered account with "the same" email.

Here's an example:
If user1 has an account with `KanyesInterventions@hotmail.com` as email address and a new user named user2 tries to register with `kanyesInterventions@icloud.com` as email, when user2 finishes the register process they get an alert saying something like "*you can't register that email because it is already in use*" but without saying the email which is in use because that would cause privacy violations.

Edit: 
This would only happen with Apple user.
When you register an Apple Account they recommend you to use your Apple ID(email you registered) as your iCloud ID(changing the extension to @icloud.com) but being totally optional. Also it is more likely to have both the same name just because we go for the easy things(my opinion). [Here's the Apple Support post.](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204053)

Maybe the system could alert you in a different way letting you know someone has already registered a **similar** email and if you are sure to register that one.

Comment: Aside from implementing such a thing being a really bad idea... what exactly is your question?

Comment: If it is a good idea to implement. Why not?

Comment: What happens when two completely different people try to register with the an email from two different domains. SgtMeowmers@gmail.com is not necessarily the same person at SgtMeowmers@hotmail.com. The email User2 used is *not* already in use, so why prevent them from signing up?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey that's a good point but my "issue" is only with Apple users. When you register and Apple Account they recommend you to use your Apple ID as your iCloud ID so you have your regular email and your iCloud email like "KanyeInterventions@hotmail.com" and "KanyeInterventions@icloud.com". As o said they recommend you not obligate you so it's totally optional but it is more likely to do it just because we are a by lazy.

Comment: I had to read util the edit to even know the context of this question.  Please edit the question so that it starts off by giving the context so that it makes sense to other users.

Comment: Weird. Because the email ***isn't being in use*** and saying it is, will really make the user wonder who's using their email...

Answer (score 1):

**Your suggesting would be poor UX**, and poor business logic.

By your logic every address that is of the form `me@mydomain.com` would be rejected because someone somewhere used a `me@....` email address.  There are many common names before the @ in email addresses, and trying to exclude me for example because there was some other iCloud user with the email address `john@something.com` is silly, considering the number of people with email addresses that follow the form `john@...`.

Comment: I think he's going to have significantly less users because he's adding such  restriction. No one will want to make a new email address just to register on the OP's site. This is a definition of a registration barrier.

Comment: It will say it is in use ONLY if "me@" and another email is registered with the "me@icloud.com". But yeah, maybe is a bad idea :) thanks

Comment: I'll bet you a large pile of cash that at least one of the few million iCloud users has an email address of the form `me@...`.  Add to that list: john, mary, steve, bob, ivan, etc.